# Service Management - Email Quick Action - Auto response

Tags: case, chatter, quickaction

we are implementing the case management.  We have set-up the channels (Email, Web).  For each channel we have setup-up an auto-reply rule.

**Use Case**
The user opens a case via email, and an auto-reply email is sent to the customer. As this happen, on the Feed tab we have this history

- auto-reply message
- original message from the customer
  (see the image)

**REQUIREMENT**
There is any way that, for the support agent, to reply directly to the customer original email, instead of the auto-reply email?
We want that, when the user clicks on "Email" action, the action should load the original message (the one sent by the customer) not the one sent the system as auto-reply.

**WORKAROUND**
We know, that the support agent, can "click on reply" from the customers' message, but this would be an extra step for the user, and we want to avoid this.

Any solution to this?

Thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check if in the support settings if you have `Create Auto-Response Record After Customer's First Email` checked. If checked I would suggest unchecking and trying your use case.

Check information about this setting [here](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000Zpz4QAC)

Comment: many thanks, i missed totally that configuration!